# How to implement Zipkin in vert.x

Tags: spring-boot, vert.x, zipkin

I want to implement Zipkin and Sleuth on vert.x application. I have Zipkin server application with Spring Boot and Spring Boot Services and its okay. I have added dependencies and setup them in application.properties and its working good. But I have one vert.x application and I have found it difficult to implement the Zipkin there. I have searched but I did not found some good example on how to implement it on vert.x application. So, what I need to do to implement the Zipkin in the vert.x application?